# Image displays with incorrect orientation

Tags: html

Apologies for the incredibly basic question but I have searched the question bank and I honestly can't see a comparable question (or at least, if it is comparable I'm too new to this to discern the relevance).

I'm trying to learn how to insert an image into a webpage. I'm using straight html at the moment not RoR. While I am able to embed an image in my html file and get the image up on screen, I can't seem to preserve the correct orientation - essentially it reproduces my jpg in landscape when it should be portrait.

I'm using the following code:

```
<img src="/Users/user/images/image.jpg" width="259" height="193" alt="Image" />
```

Which presents the image with what should be the left hand edge as its base; I have tried switching the dimensions but that simply leads to a taller version of the image, still sitting on what should be the left hand edge. I can't see anything in the html Dog pages that explains this issue...

Comment: By looking at your parameters width and height it seems to be a landscape picture (height is smaller than width)

Comment: what exactly you want to do here?

Comment: Please clarify if it is incorrect orientation or incorrect aspect ratio.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the speedy responses. To try and clarify: the picture is definitely meant to be in portrait (it shows correctly in portrait in Finder), but neither 259*193 nor 193*259 show the image correctly in my page - 259*153 preserves the correct aspect ratio, but with what should be the left hand edge as the base of the image. What I'm trying to do is to show the image in its correct orientation.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using css3 somewhere?

Comment: Pretty sure there's no styling going on there - I've inspected in firebug and it tells me "This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it."

Comment: you can't change image orientation using html, you need to do it using paint or something

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with the EXIF orientation information. I can't offer you a full solution, but you may write a PHP script that will apply the rotation by re-ordering the pixel order of the JPEG and then remove the orientation info from the EXIF.

Answer (score 0):

Check if u have any CSS class that apply on the img

Try to set the width only

```
<img src="Users/user/images/image.jpg" width="259" alt="Image" />
```

Comment: OK - tried that, didn't see any change at all in the image on screen. (I'm not actually applying any CSS so that's probably why?)

Comment: what exactly do u need to see ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just specify the width, the height will be scaled automatically according to the aspect ratio of the original image, vice versa if you just specify the height.